# Official way to get the Thread Information/Environment Block (TIB/TEB)

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime

In Windows, it's long been common, if undocumented, knowledge that the Thread Information Block (TIB) of the current thread can be found at FS:0. But that only works on Intel CPUs, where the FS register exists in the first place. Now I wanna get to the TIB on an ARM-based Windows system (Windows Phone and maybe Windows RT). Is there an API for that, please?

EDIT: I want to get the thread stack base for crash reporting purposes.

Information about TIB/TEB: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2CE.aspx

Comment: What are you trying to extract specifically?  There is likely an API that is suited to your needs that doesn't require a hack like that.

Comment: Stack top, for dumping the stack, for crash reporting.

Comment: Get the stack pointer from the context record included in the exception pointers. Or just read it directly from the sp register.

Comment: Raymond Chen? For reals?? Oh wow. *hyperventilates* Anyway, bad choice of words on my part. Stack bottom, then. The high-addressed end of the stack. The place the stack grows from. SP is easy to grab, I do that already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The macro `NtCurrentTeb()` is available in `winnt.h` for all supported architectures, including ARM (Windows RT):

```
#if defined(_M_ARM) && !defined(__midl) && !defined(_M_CEE_PURE)

__forceinline
struct _TEB *
NtCurrentTeb (
    VOID
    )
{
    return (struct _TEB *)(ULONG_PTR)_MoveFromCoprocessor(CP15_TPIDRURW);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To answer your posted question, you can use [`NtQueryInformationThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx) to retrieve a `THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure, which contains a pointer to the thread's `TIB` in its `TebBaseAddress` member.

Comment: I like Igor's answer better :)

Answer (score 4):

Igor nailed it. But FYI, in ARM assembly it goes like this:

```
mrc p15, 0, r12, c13, c0, 2 ; r12 now points at TEB/TIB
ldr r12, [r12, #4] ; r12 now holds stack base
```