# Free TLS pointers for every thread

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, thread-local-storage

Reading the following page in MSDN:

[Using Thread Local Storage in a Dynamic-Link Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686997.aspx)

I can't understand who is responsible for freeing the memory pointed by the TLS slot of each thread in the case of a `FreeLibrary()` call.

From what I understand, if I have several running threads, all of them allocated memory inside a TLS slot in a given index. When `FreeLibrary()` is called, only `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is triggered, so only the thread which receives the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` notification has a chance to call `LocalFree()` on its own data stored in the TLS slot, before calling `TlsFree()` on the index. This causes a memory leak in all of the other threads that don't have a chance to call `LocalFree()` on their data, as they don't receive a `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notification.

Can someone explain when and where  the buffers stored in TLS slots of each thread should be freed?

Comment: if your DLL assign data to some thread - it must not be unloaded until it not free this data (on thread exit). so or your DLL must not be unloaded at all in this case. or you need  increment reference count to DLL when you assign data to thread. and decrement reference count to DLL when you release this data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the documentation you linked to:

> When a thread terminates, the entry-point function is called with the DLL_THREAD_DETACH value and the memory for that thread is freed.

That is the ideal time when the memory pointed to by the TLS slot should be freed, if the thread did not already do so before terminating.  This is demonstrated in the example code provided:

```
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    // Release the allocated memory for this thread.
    lpvData = TlsGetValue(dwTlsIndex);
    if (lpvData != NULL)
        LocalFree((HLOCAL) lpvData);
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    // Release the allocated memory for this thread.
    lpvData = TlsGetValue(dwTlsIndex);
    if (lpvData != NULL)
        LocalFree((HLOCAL) lpvData);
    // Release the TLS index.
    TlsFree(dwTlsIndex);
    break;
```

However, per the [DllMain entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) documentation:

> When a DLL is unloaded from a process as a result of an unsuccessful load of the DLL, termination of the process, **or a call to `FreeLibrary`**, the system does not call the DLL's entry-point function with the `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` value for the individual threads of the process. The DLL is only sent a `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` notification. **DLLs can take this opportunity to clean up all resources for all threads known to the DLL**.

So, you would have to keep track of the pointers you store in per-thread TLS slots in such a way that any pointers not already freed by the `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` handler can be later freed by the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` handler.  For instance, by storing the pointers in a global thread-safe list.

---

**Update**: an alternative solution would be to have the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` handler enumerate running threads, accessing the TIB/TEB (Thread Information/Environment Block) struct for each thread. [`NtQueryInformationThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx) can be used to [retrieve a pointer to a thread's TIB/TEB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301032/). Amongst other things, [the TIB/TEB also contains a pointer to the thread's TLS array](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2CE.aspx).

---

**Update**: On Vista+, an alternative solution is to use FLS (fiber local storage) instead of TLS (thread local storage). The [`FlsAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664.aspx) function takes an optional callback. The [`FlsCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682665.aspx) documentation states:

> An application-defined function. If the FLS slot is in use, FlsCallback is called on fiber deletion, thread exit, and **when an FLS index is freed**.

And the [`FlsFree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682667.aspx) documentation states:

> Freeing an FLS index frees the index for all instances of FLS in the current process. **Freeing an FLS index also causes the associated callback routine to be called for each fiber, if the corresponding FLS slot contains a non-NULL value**.

Per the [Fibers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661.aspx) documentation:

> A fiber can use fiber local storage (FLS) to create a unique copy of a variable for each fiber. **If no fiber switching occurs, FLS acts exactly the same as thread local storage. The FLS functions (`FlsAlloc`, `FlsFree`, `FlsGetValue`, and `FlsSetValue`) manipulate the FLS associated with the current thread**. If the thread is executing a fiber and the fiber is switched, the FLS is also switched.

Comment: but question was - if dll will be unloaded *before* some threads, for which tls data allocated, terminated

Comment: yes, you right. this (keep track of the pointers) one of possible solution.

Comment: Fls really the best solution here and it show that root of problem with Tls is not well design it functional initially by windows

Comment: "If the thread is executing a fiber and the fiber is switched, the FLS is also switched." - typo in doc? It seems should be "and the _thread_ is switched".

Comment: No, the doc is correct. Did you even read the entire doc on what fibers actually are? A single thread can run multiple fibers and switch between them at will (that is the whole point of fibers - manual scheduling).  So, when a thread switches between fibers, the thread's FLS is switched accordingly, just as the doc says.